# Nextjs: ts(7031) type error: Binding element 'Component' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, tsx, react-tsx

This is an issue I had when converting a NextJS project to TypeScript. In my `_app.tsx`, I got a type error: `Binding element 'pageProps' implicitly has an 'any' type. ts(7031)`. The error likely looks like this: [image]

I know that there are existing answers for this somewhere on StackOverflow, but I am writing this so that someone in the future might come across this easier.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The solution to this is simple.
NextJS exports a custom type to resolve this issue: `AppProps`.
It can be imported like this:

```
import { AppProps } from 'next/app';
```

To apply the type, you can reformat the props from

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```

to

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```

The final product should look like this, assuming an unmodified `_app.tsx` file:

```
import { AppProps } from 'next/app';

import '../styles/globals.css'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```